# @mysql/xdevapi ECONNREFUSED doesn't release connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-x-devapi

I'm using the @mysql/xdevapi npm package (version 8.0.22) with a local installation of mysql-8.0.15-winx64.

I have set pooling to enabled and attempted to retrieve a session from the client. If I do this before mysql is ready then I get an ECONNREFUSED exception which is expected, but the connection never appears to be released. If the pool size is one then all subsequent attempts to getSession

The exception is thrown from within the getSession method, so the session is not returned for me to call `.end()` manually.

```
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
const client = mysqlx.getClient(config, { pooling: { enabled: true, maxSize: 1, queueTimeout: 2000 } });
const session = await this.client.getSession(); // returns ECONNREFUSED exception

/*
wait for mysql to be ready and accepting connections
*/

const session = await this.client.getSession(); // returns connection pool queue timeout exception because the previous session hasn't been returned to the pool
```

How can I ensure that the aborted connection is returned to the pool?

Comment: It should say I can't call `.close()` manually. Sorry I can't edit the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and I encourage you to report it at https://bugs.mysql.com/ using the `Connector for Node.js` category.

The only workaround that comes to mind is re-creating the pool if the `getSession()` method returns a rejected `Promise` (with or without a specific error). For instance, something like:

```
const poolConfig = { pooling: { enabled: true, maxSize: 1, queueTimeout: 2000 } }
let pool = mysqlx.getClient(config, poolConfig)

let session = null

try {
  session = await pool.getSession()
} catch (err) {
  await pool.close()
  pool = mysqlx.getClient(config, poolConfig)

  session = await pool.getSession()
  // do something
}
```

It's an ugly solution and there's a chance it might be hard to shoehorn into your design but, at least, it lets you enjoy the other benefits of a connection pool.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thanks, I reported the bug. I already had a similar workaround but I don't call getSession again inside the catch because the error is just likely to happen again. Instead I recreate the pool and then rethrow the error so the application can retry after some interval.